# How to get input from a txt file?

Tags: python, input

How we can pass inputs from a file to a function in a loop?

Example this function:

```
def fx():

    while True:
        x = input()

        if x == 'hi':
            return 'hello'

        elif x == 'bye':
            break
```

and on terminal we call the function:

```
fx()
```

Now pass the lines of txt file as inputs,  with this lines:
hi
nice day
bye

Based on others posts, I'm think is something like context manner will work, but I don't know how to pass the inputs, when the function is active.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as arq:
    for line in arq:
        # need send input here
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correct, why can't you call the function for each line and pass the line to the function and use that as `x` inside the function?

Comment: The line `x = input()' takes user input from the command line. If you're trying to read input from a file, then you do not need that.

Comment: @Austin can`t call the function for each line, need to be one call and several inputs.

Comment: @ekmcd because the txt file will have hundreds lines, and will be more than one txt input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If modifying the code is okay, then try:

```
def fx():
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line == 'hi':
                return 'hello'
            elif line == 'bye':
                break

fx()
```

Else provide `input.txt` as `stdin` by using the command `python file_name.py < input.txt`.

Comment: that modify the original function, have a way to do this without change the function?

Comment: Use the command "python file_name.py < input.txt" to run the code.